# Must be equal and other stacked math symbols

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Several times already I wanted to express something like

```
  !
A = B
```

or

```
   n->0
X ------> oo
```

in a math environment. **How do I achieve this?**

On a related note: What is the correct term for this? Googling for `!` and `=` unsurprisingly doesn't yield too many useful results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the code below, I create a new command, `\mbeq` (short for "must be equal"...), which is a "math relational" operator (same type as the "ordinary" equal sign). Using the `\overset` command in the definition of the `\mbeq` operator automatically makes the new command "inherit" the type of the second argument of the `\overset` command; hence, it's not necessarily to assign the type "mathrel" explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 % "mbeq": must be equal
\newcommand{\mbeq}{\overset{!}{=}}
\begin{document}
$ a\mbeq b$, $x\xrightarrow{n\to 0}\infty$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, I'm not aware of a commonly used term for the "must be equal" symbol (exclamation mark set over equality symbol). I searched *detexify*, and no predefined symbol came up.

Comment: As I said in another comment, the `\mathrel` here is redundant, because `\overset` usually guesses right. But +1 for suggesting a new command for it.

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \overset{!}{=}\qquad x\xrightarrow{n\to 0}\infty \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Rather than `\stackrel` I'd recommend `\overset`

Comment: @egreg: right. I've edited my answer, thanks.

Comment: @egreg: In this \case, there is no difference between the visual output of `\stackrel` and `\overset`. I guess the only motivation behind it is that it has an `\underset` counterpart which makes it more generic in terms of usage.

Comment: @Werner That's a happy case. Try with `\stackrel{!}{x}` and you'll see the difference. Besides, `\overset` tries to guess the nature of the main symbol (relation or operation), so using the correct spacing; conversely, `\stackrel` always creates a relation.