# insert zero height newline

Tags: spacing, overset

I have the following

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 a_{m,m} &\overset{(\eqref{eq:masssplitAIndex},\eqref{eq:masssplitLinvIndex})}{=} 1 - a \\
 &\overset{
  \substack{\eqref{eq:masssplitLinvIndex} \\ % too much space here
            \hphantom{\meqref{eq:masssplitAIndex,eq:masssplitLinvIndex}}
            }
          }
  }{=} 1 - a.
 \end{align}
```

\end{document}

What is the proper solution to stack (with zero skip) a hphantom box above the (0.33) in the figure such that the spacing to the equal sign is correct?)

[image]

Comment: take a look at the answer here about `\overset`: [Must be equal and other stacked math symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32290/579)

Answer (score 2):

The following example uses `\stackrel` to put the references above the equals sign. The phantom for the second line is set via `\ooalign` to avoid the explicit measurement of the references of the previous equation.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{32}
\begin{gather}
  \label{eq:masssplitLinvIndex}
  \text{mass split L inv index}
\\
  \label{eq:masssplitAtIndex}
  \text{mass split at index}
\end{gather}

\begin{align}
  a_{m,m}
  & \stackrel{(\ref{eq:masssplitAtIndex},\,\ref{eq:masssplitLinvIndex})}{=}
  1
\\
  & \stackrel{%
      \ooalign{%
        \phantom{%
          $\scriptstyle
          (\ref{eq:masssplitAtIndex},\,\ref{eq:masssplitLinvIndex})$%
        }\cr
        \hfil$\scriptstyle(\ref{eq:masssplitLinvIndex})$\hfil
      }%
    }{=}
  1
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `alignat` together with a hack for centering a column's contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Cen}[2]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    #2%
  \else
    \makebox[\ifcase\expandafter #1\maxcolumn@widths\fi]{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{32}
\begin{gather}
x\label{eq:masssplitAIndex}\\
y\label{eq:masssplitLinvIndex}
\end{gather}

Now the main thing:
\begin{alignat}{2}
 a_{m,m} &\Cen{2}{\overset{(\ref{eq:masssplitAIndex},\ref{eq:masssplitLinvIndex})}{=}{}} && 1 - a \\
 &\Cen{2}{\overset{\eqref{eq:masssplitLinvIndex}}{=}}&& 1 - a.
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209732/4427 for `\Cen`

However, I'd prefer a simpler thing:

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
a_{m,m} &= 1-a &&\qquad\text{by (\ref{eq:masssplitAIndex}, \ref{eq:masssplitLinvIndex})} \\
        &= 1-a &&\qquad\text{by \eqref{eq:masssplitLinvIndex}}
\end{alignat}
```

[image]